# How to query in the given order

Tags: oracle, select, order-by, where

```sql
select * from table where options=(10,223,43,1,23,54,323,32)
```

But the result is not coming in the given order of options. Options need to be changed frequently.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to use the `IN` operator with multiple values. `WHERE options IN (10,223,43,1,23,54,323,32)` Secondly, relational databases are agnostic about row order and can return them in any order they want, which can change with different execution plans. To force them to return in a particular order that's meaningful to you, add the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE options IN (10,223,43,1,23,54,323,32) ORDER BY options
```

Will return them in numerical order of the options value. If instead you want them ordered in some other way, such as the order in which you have shown your `IN` clause, you need to do a bit of magic with the `DECODE` to construct an ascending pseudo-value by which to order the results:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE options IN (10,223,43,1,23,54,323,32) 
 ORDER BY DECODE(options,10,1,
                         223,2,
                         43,3,
                         23,4,
                         54,5,
                         323,6,
                         32,7)
```

You could get away with listing them only once, but it would not perform well on a large table because it wouldn't be able to use indexes:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT x.*,
               DECODE(options,10,1,
                              223,2,
                              43,3,
                              23,4,
                              54,5,
                              323,6,
                              32,7) seq
          FROM table x)
 WHERE seq > 0
 ORDER BY seq
```

Be careful, though, if this is too be used with high frequency and a variable number of options, as that will create a lot of unsharable cursors, even with bind variables, due to the varying size of the `IN` and `DECODE` argument list. If this will be used with high frequency, I would instead recommend inserting the options and order sequence into a temp table and then selecting from it and joining to your real table. That way you don't have to list any options in your SQL at all.